# Web server is shut down - jqGrid behaves as if nothing were wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I use jqGrid 4.5.4 for data editing: records are edited in a dialogue (i.e. it's not inline editing).

In the edit options I have `reloadAfterSubmit:false` and `closeAfterEdit:true`. When a user attempts to modify a record, and an error happens on the server, the dialogue stays open and shows an error message to the user (it's a correct behaviour).

However, **when the web server is down** (i.e. I open the page and then I shut down the web server), **the grid behaves as if there is no problem at all**: the dialogue gets closed and the new values appear in the grid. It's a very confusing behaviour: the user may think that s/he updated the data in the DB. I have the same problem with adding and deleting records.  Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When web server is shut down, all HTTP responses have the `Aborted` status in Firebug. In JavaScript code, they can be recognized by the `0` HTTP status code.

One way to fix the problem described in the question is catching all `Aborted` responses in the jQuery's global `ajaxError` event handler and displaying an error page. I use code similar to the following:

```js
var documentIsUnloaded = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).ajaxError(ajaxErrorHandler);

    // `Aborted` responses can also happen when a user leaves a
    // page before an AJAX request is completed. We need to avoid these instances.
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
        // The user left the page; there is no need to show the error page
        documentIsUnloaded = true;
    });
});

function ajaxErrorHandler(event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {

    if(documentIsUnloaded) {
        return; // the user left the page; there is no need to show the error page
    }

    if(jqxhr.status == 0) {
        // display error page here!
    }
}
```

Another way to fix the problem is using jqGrid's `afterSubmit` callback:

```js
function afterSubmitCallback(response, postdata) {
    if(response.status == 0) {
        return [ false, "Cannot connect to the server.", 0 ];
    }
    else {
        return [ true, "", 0 ];
    }
}
```

This callback should be registered in Add, Edit and Delete options in jqGrid (`afterSubmit:afterSubmitCallback`). jqGrid will show the error message in the Add/Edit/Delete dialogue.